# React crash on render bundled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, esbuild

I got the error Invalid hook call when try to render bundled component in another react app.
[image]

My component build script is look like this:

```
 "build": "esbuild ./src/index.js --external:'react' --bundle --format=cjs --loader:.js=jsx --outdir=dist",
```

and the component has peer dependency of react:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  },
```

when I bundle it and then pack it or copy the bundle to another react project it's throw this error.

I run the

```
npm list
```

and didnt find any extra version of react

[image]

I know the component code is fine because when I run directly the component using story-book it's render just fine.

I tried to use single peerDependency version of react and I checked all the versions

Comment: Can you please add the component that you used hooks in it?

Comment: Along with providing the problematic component code, have a look at [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) in case you are breaking some of these.

Comment: As I mentioned the component run fine when I use it directly with story-book
you can check out the component here: https://github.com/ofirelarat/react-multistep

Comment: I looked on the rules of hooks in react docs and tried the eslint plugin that check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! There was a syntax error in the `esbuild` command:

```
"build": "esbuild ./src/index.js \"--define:process.env.NODE_ENV='production'\" --external:react --bundle --format=cjs --loader:.js=jsx --outdir=dist && cp -f ./dist/index.js ./example/index.js",
```

Excluding react from the bundle probably didn't work, after removing the quotation mark it works fine.